# Convert an int and bytearray into a ByteString Python struct Socket

Tags: python, sockets, struct, byte, arrays

i need to send 1 int und 1 bytearray(200) through a socket to a server.
The socket.send() function only accpets exactly one string so i need the int and bytearray as bytes in one String.
I tryed to convert both to a string with struct.pack(), which is working well for the int but not for the bytearray.

```
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
    print "Connected to: ",  s.getpeername()
    #Trying to put int and bytearray into 1 string
    a= 02 # int
    b= bytearray(200) #bytearray
    c = struct.pack("B", a)
    c += b



    s.send(c)
    print s.recv(1024)
```

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: i know it wont work this way but i dont have any solution for the bytearray so far..

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: i need to send the int and the array(200bytes, but the array is empty)both in bytecode.If i use falsetru's solution i get an unhandled typeerror "bytearray object is not callable", if try to use my code there is no error but the server doesnt accpet the message

Comment: I don't see why your bytearray is empty. I just tested this successfully between my client and server. My server replied with exactly what I sent, using your exact same code. Can you show me the array as empty?

Comment: the server only accpets input: id:byte; data:array[0..200]ofByte.my data array has to be empty because my request only needs the id.i have to send one string with the int 02 as id and the 200byte array. This String has to be in bytecode or the server will not understand the request

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "server doesnt accpet the message"?

Comment: If you print `bytearray` part in C (using `puts`, `printf("..%s..", ..)`, ...), it will print nothing because the bytearray contains 200 **null bytes**.

Comment: the server expects an id and data.The id tells the server what to do and the data are some(not always required) extra information.if i dont send both of them the server returns a exeption message.

Comment: I understand what the server expects. But you are writing that the server doesn't accept the message. This can mean a number of things so I'm asking for clarification. Does the socket not accept? Is the socket accepting but erroring out? Is the socket accepting and data is being parsed but not behaving correctly? Please be more specific.

Comment: the socket and server accept the code.

Comment: Great. So what's the expected behavior then? Is the server failing to parse the first byte?

Comment: yeah i think so, i am trying right now to figure out what string the server gets, so i can tell if there is a convertion problem, i will post again if i get a result.

Comment: Using wireshark will confirm what data is sent and received.

Comment: ok, i figured out what was wrong:

Comment: i used the wrong port, error message was the same so i didtn recognize...feel pretty stupid right now :D anyways thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatenate them:

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.pack('<l', 1234) + bytearray([0]*10)
b'\xd2\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

or also specify the bytearray:

```
>>> struct.pack('<l10s', 1234, bytearray([0]*10)) # In Python 3.x
# struct.pack('<l10s', 1234, bytes(bytearray([0]*10))) # In Python 2.x
b'\xd2\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

Comment: Shouldn't the packing be big-endian? My checksum is incorrect when sending as little-endian.

Comment: @EugeneC., It depends on what opponent expect. As you may know, it's easy to produce big-endian/network-endian packed bytes. (`>` or `!` instead of `<`)

Comment: Also, not sure if this is version-specific, but your second struct example errors out if bytearray is not cast as a string. I'm running 2.7.5

Comment: @EugeneC., You're right. The second code should be adjusted. I updated the answer according your comment. Thank you.